# config proxy in angular cli

Tags: javascript, angular, reverse-proxy

I want to use proxy  config in angular-cli

this is my file:

```
{
    "/api/server": {
        "target": "http://other-site/server",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": { "^/api/server": "" },
        "changeOrigin": true
    },
    "/api/group": {
        "target": "http://other-site/group",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": { "^/api/group": "" },
        "changeOrigin": true
    },
    "/api/group/activate": {
        "target": "http://other-site/group/activate",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": { "^/api/group/activate": "" },
        "changeOrigin": true
    } 
}
```

it works for me , but i need a other effective solution ( juste remove pattern /api  and concatinate with target , for example;

```
 change "/api/server" to "http://other-site/server" ...etc
```

i am  trying with the code below, but doesn't work

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://other-site/",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""},
        "changeOrigin": true
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use pattern **"/api/*"** ,Try  with this:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://other-site",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" },
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```